# Is there a difference in memory management outcomes between using an object as an argument or a spread copy of the object?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

Is there a difference between how garbage collection works when an object is passed directly as an argument to a function or the spread copy of the object is passed instead?

```js
const myObject = {
 a: 1
}


function pureFunction(objectArg){
  // do something
}


// is option #2 better for garbage collection than option #1?

// option 1
pureFunction(myObject);

// option 2
pureFunction({ ...myObject })
```

Comment: The copy can be discarded when the function returns (assuming it's not closed over), but also you had to make a copy. What are you trying to optimise here?

Comment: I just saw a tutorial where it suggests that passing a variable into a closure makes it hard for the GC to track the variable going forward.  This made me wonder whether it was preferable to pass copies of objects rather than the actual objects themselves to avoid this issue.

Comment: The spread operator will not deep copy the original object. If there are nested objects in `myObject` and if one or more nested objects are going to stay in a function's scope then even if the original `myObject` reference is removed, the child objects will stay in the memory; probably without even being moved to a new location in the memory. It really depends on the JS engine running the code.